# Extracting .ovl and .aux files?

Tags: decompress

I recently got a copy of a space game and id like to be able to extract the audio/models from the game.

I've attached an example .ovl file and a .aux file below. 
I have no knowledge on reverse engineering file formats.
So I'm sorry if I'm not the best at learning things. 
However i will try to do the best that I can.  I was able to gather a bit of information on the web. However no one has archived this yet.

> 'The OVL and OVS files are compressed with zlib. OVL files make up
>   parts of a virtual serialized filesystem, and are partially
>   compressed. OVS files are completely compressed and contains most of
>   the bulk data. Can't give you more info than that at the moment as I'm
>   at work and I've not looked at them for a while.'

Here is the top of the .aux file in hex workshop.

[image]

Here is the .ovl file.

[image]

Quick Update: I was able to extract some of the files and get the proper name. However, I'm not able too play them. They're corupt.

I used this quickbms script.

http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&p=74664#p74664

[image]

OVL FILE DOWNLOAD: 
/mega.co.nz/#!Cx5nHLTa!JgTCENPHMY4MD1LeOLFhwwt8DcZr8pngforLIdPibqs

AUX FILE DOWNLOAD: 
/mega.co.nz/#!60YAkQ5Q!6M_aexZSx8JyE7GQAKi1K1qD17n9ULOMGKM7t26BaUs

Comment: From your source of that quote, also: [Frontier Developments](http://www.frontier.co.uk) ".. have already said that they will not release details of the file formats and politely requested that people do not reverse engineer them."

Comment: I guess you could start reading [here](http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php?title=DGTEFF) for some insights...

Comment: I updated the thread.